# Problems with constant iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I'm trying write a tempate function which takes a sequence (by 2 iterators) and calculates the number of permutations of this sequence, in which there are no consecutive identical elements.
Thats what i did

```
    template<class Iterator>
    size_t count_perm(Iterator p, Iterator q)
    {
        if (p == q)
            return 1;
        size_t count = 0;
        while(std::next_permutation(p, q)){
              if(std::adjacent_find(p,q) != q)
              ++count;
        }
    }
/*Example

std::array<int, 3> a1 = {1,2,3};
size_t c1 = count_perm(a1.begin(), a1.end()); // 6

std::array<int, 5> a2 = {1,2,3,4,4};
size_t c2 = count_perm(a2.begin(), a2.end()); // 36*/
```

This code not working if i pass const iterators. What should I change to make it work with const iterators?

Comment: I would suggest you talk to the guys at https://math.stackexchange.com/. I bet they can give you a much more efficient way to do your calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this exercise as follows, it works with const iterators:

```
template<class Iterator>
size_t count_permutations(Iterator p, Iterator q)
{
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    if (p == q)
        return 1;
    std::vector<T> v(p,q);
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    size_t count = 0;
    do{
        if(std::adjacent_find(v.begin(),v.end()) == v.end()) {
            ++count;
        }

    } while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    return count;
}
```

Problem was to use `std::type_traits<Iterator>::value_type` instead `Iterator::value_type` (that not working with const iters and simple pointers (like int*))

Answer (score 2):

> This code not working if i pass const iterators. What should I change to make it work with const iterators?

You can't: `std::next_permutation()` modify the values so is incompatible with const iterators.

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> How can i implement this function in right way?

I suggest you to follows the suggestion from Jarod42: works over a copy.

I propose something as follows

```
template <class Container>
size_t count_perm (Container c)  // note: c is a copy
{
    if ( c.cbegin() == c.cend() )
        return 1;

    size_t count = 0U;

    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());

    if (std::adjacent_find(c.cbegin(), c.cend()) != c.cend()))
     {
       std::size_t ui = c.size();

       for ( count = ui ; --ui > 1 ; count *= ui )
        ; 

       // count now is c.size() ! (factorial of)
     }
    else
     {
       while (std::next_permutation(c.begin(), c.end()))
          if (std::adjacent_find(c.cbegin(), c.cend()) != c.cend())
             ++count;
     }

    return count; // remember this return!
}
```

Comment: *"What should I change to make it work with const iterators?"*: Create copy :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 - I know; but I think sometimes is better to be tranchants to point in evidence the problem.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks guys. How can i implement this function in right way?

Comment: "why not zero?" Because there's exactly one resulting set: The empty set.

Comment: I think you also need to sort the collection first, or you’ll miss some permutations.

Comment: @max66, except it doesnt make sense. If container is empty {} the return is 1. If container contains 1 element, the return is 0. If container contains 2 elements the return is 2,

Comment: @KillzoneKid: So what? 0 elements gives you `{}`, 1 element gives  you `{a}`, 2 elements gives you `{a,b},{b,a}`. Those counts are 1, 1, and 2. That's correct.

Comment: @Mooing Duck the counts are {} - 1; {1} - 0; {1,2} - 2

Comment: and `{a, a}` should be 0 :-)

Comment: @KillzoneKid: You're missing the `{2,1}` permutation. I can't say what the code actually does, only what I think it's supposed to do.

Comment: @KillzoneKid - the empty container element is a borderline case and is questionable (but I find absolutely reasonable consider the empty set as a permutation that leave the empty container with "no consecutive identical elements"); but is questionable, as said. When the container contains only an element, there is only one possible permutation and that permutation leave ever the container with "no consecutive identical elements". So for one element the return value should be ever 1, not zero.

Comment: @max66 I agree, however `if ( c.cbegin() == c.cend() )` only true when there are 0 elements in the container. `>>So for one element the return value should be ever 1, not zero` When there is 1 element your code would return 0 I would expect.

Comment: @KillzoneKid - for empty containers: yes, and in that case seems me reasonable return 1; for containers with 1 elements: D'Oh! You're right; there was an error in my code and I've corrected the problem when you where writing the precedent comment. I was forgetting to consider the first iteration. But there is a similar error in your answer: if you initialize `count` with `1`, you take for granted that the initial (ordered) permutation is with "no consecutive identical elements"; this is true only if there aren't identical element in the container; you have to check also the first permutation.

Comment: @user1786089 - corrected and improved my answer: as pointed by KillzoneKid, there was an error in my example: I din't consider the initial (ordered) permutation; otherwise if the first permutation is with no adjacent, *all* permutation are without adjacent, so you can directly return the total number of permutations, `N!` (factorial of `N`, where `N` is `c.size()`, the number of elements in the container).

Comment: @max66 this is what `std::all_of` is for in my answer, this is to make sure that the first call will not contain adjacent elements, therefore 1 permutation is guaranteed.

Comment: @KillzoneKid - not noticed; sorry. But what are you checking, exactly? That there are elements not equal to the first one? And if you check that the first iteration (before `std::sort()`) isn't without adjacent, you return immediately zero when are possible permutations without adjacent? Sorry, not sure to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your templated function for you (still requires non-const iterators):

```
template<class Iterator> size_t count_perm(Iterator p, Iterator q)
{
    if (p == q || std::all_of(p, q, [&](auto &el) {return el == *p; })))
        return 0;

    size_t count = 1;
    std::sort(p, q);

    while (std::next_permutation(p, q)) 
        if (std::adjacent_find(p, q) == q)
            ++count;

    return count;
}
```

1. you should return count
2. when no adjacent elements are found, `std::adjacent_find` returns `end`, so you should `== q` not `!= q`

Your example produces 6 and 37. Should it be 36 instead of 37?

Comment: Whereas you remove the requirement of order, you don't fix constness OP's issue of the range.

Comment: @Jarod42 I know, the function wasn't usable with or without const iterator before. Could create temp container inside the function, but I don't know if this would be best solution